# Issue With My School Assignment on Classes

Tags: c++, class

So I have an assignment due in my C++ class on classes, and I'm having some trouble. Here is the description of the assignment:

Programming Challenge 7 on page 499 of your text asks you to design and Inventory Class that can hold information for an item in a retail store's inventory. You are given the code for the creation of the class along with code for the implementation of the functions. Demonstrate the class by writing a simple program that uses it. This program should demonstrate that each function works correctly. Submit your .cpp file using the link provided.

And here are the contents of the file sent (it's quite lengthy):

```
// Chapter 7---Files for Programming Challenge 13---Inventory Class

// This is the inventory.h file.
// It contains the Inventory class declaration.

#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

class Inventory
{
private:
    int itemNumber;
    int quantity;
    double cost;
    double totalCost;
public:
    // Default constructor
    Inventory()
        { itemNumber = quantity = cost = totalCost = 0; }

    // Overloaded constructor
    Inventory(int, int, double);    // Defined in Inventory.cpp

    // Mutators (i.e., "set" functions) defined in Inventory.cpp
    void setItemNumber(int);
    void setQuantity(int);
    void setCost(double);

    // setTotalCost calculates the total cost
    // and stores the result in the totalCost member
    void setTotalCost()
        { totalCost = cost * quantity; }

    // Accessors (i.e., "get" functions)
    int getItemNumber()
        { return itemNumber; }
    int getQuantity()
        { return quantity; }
    double getCost()
        { return cost; }
    double getTotalCost()
        { return totalCost; }

    // Input validation functions
    bool validInt(int);
    bool validFloat(double);
};

#endif

// This is the inventory.cpp file.
// It contains the Inventory class function definitions. 

#include <iostream>
#include "Inventory.h"
using namespace std;

//************************************************************
// Overloaded constructor
// Accepts arguments to be stored in each member variable.
//************************************************************
Inventory::Inventory(int in, int q, double c)
{ 
    setItemNumber(in);
    setQuantity(q);
    setCost(c);
    setTotalCost();
}

//************************************************************
// setItemNumber accepts an argument to be stored in item number.
//************************************************************
void Inventory::setItemNumber(int in)
{
    while (!validInt(in))
    {
        cout << "Item Number must be positive. Please re-enter: ";
        cin  >> in;
    }
    itemNumber = in; 
}

//************************************************************
// setQuantity accepts an argument to be stored in quantity.
//************************************************************
void Inventory::setQuantity(int q)
{
    while (!validInt(q))
    {
        cout << "Quantity must be positive. Please re-enter: ";
        cin  >> q;
    }
    quantity = q; 
}

//************************************************************
// setCost accepts an argument to be stored in cost.
//************************************************************
void Inventory::setCost(double c)
{
    while (!validInt(c))
    {
        cout << "Cost must be positive. Please re-enter: ";
        cin  >> c;
    }
    cost = c; 
}

//************************************************************
// The validInt member tests its integer argument to see 
// if it is negative. If the argument is negative, the function 
// returns false. Otherwise, the function returns true.
//************************************************************
bool Inventory::validInt(int value)
{
    if (value < 0)    // the value is negative so it is NOT valid
        return false;
    else              // the integer value is valid
        return true;  
}

//************************************************************
// The validFloat member tests its floating-point argument to see
// if it is negative. If the argument is negative, the function 
// returns false. Otherwise, the function returns true.
//************************************************************
bool Inventory::validFloat(double value)
{
    if (value < 0)    // the value is negative so it is NOT valid
        return false;
    else              // the floating-point value is valid
        return true;
}
```

I'm just not sure how to use this information to make a program that demonstrates the class, and it could be as simple as me not saving the file the correct way

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Far too much code, and you've not asked a specific question we can answer. If you can't figure out how to get started on the assignment, ask your instructor for help. This site is for *specific questions* about *actual problems you're facing*; being unable to start your homework isn't a specific problem. Your instructor apparently hasn't yet done the job of proving enough information for you to do the work; ask them for additional help. It's what they're being paid to do. Also, your title is meaningless, as it does nothing to describe a specific problem or ask a question.

Comment: :(  @ the validFloat function

Comment: To start: write a new file called say `main.cpp` - in the same directory as `inventory.h` - containing the text: `#include "inventory.h"` `int main() { Inventory inventory; inventory.setItemNumber(33); }`.  That creates an inventory object and invokes one member function on it. Go from there... think up some uses for the functions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I especially like how `validFloat` operates on the `double` type. Stay classy, textbooks!

Answer (score 1):

Just write a `main` function which instantiates an `Inventory` object and calls each of its methods in a meaningful way. This isn't a puzzle, just find a way to call the functions that makes sense to you.